# Three.js : how can I remove the "lines" of the triangles from the rendering when using THREE.CanvasRenderer?

Tags: three.js, rendering

I'm playing with Three.js and everythings works fine with WebGL.

But on Internet Explorer 10, it doesn't work. So I've tried to use THREE.CanvasRenderer() instead of Three.WebGLRenderer().

The problem is that the rendering is different.
With THREE.CanvasRenderer(), between each triangle we can see some spaces which lead to displaying grey lines.

I want to get rid of the lines with this renderer.
I've put {antialias: true}
Below is a screenshot with both rendererers :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer :)
I have to put the property overdraw to true when using materials.
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1044

Comment: Actually, `overdraw` takes a numeric value between 0 and 1 now. For example, 0.5. See `Material.js`. three.js r.61